# Creating a function that returns index of minimum value in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def minimum_index(xs):
    minimum_index=xs[0]
    for i in range(len(xs)):
    if xs[i]<xs[i+1]:
        min_i=i
    elif xs[i]>xs[i+1]:
        min_i=i+1
        continue
return minimum_index
```

This looks correct to me, but for some reason, I keep trying to change things around and I either get an incorrect return value or no return value.

Comment: `minimum_index` never changes from `xs[0]`.

Comment: please fix indentation, this way it is a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the function

```
def minimum_index(xs):
    ans = 0
    for i in range(1, len(xs)):
        if xs[i] < xs[ans]:
            ans = i
    return ans
```

or in a more pythonic way

```
minimum_index = lambda xs: xs.index(min(xs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has at least two issues: You seem to have two variables that stand for the minimal index, and you mix them up. Also, it is not enough to compare subsequent elements, you will have to compare to the minimal value. Try this:

`def minimum_index(xs):
    minx = xs[0]
    mini = 0
    for i in range(1,len(xs)):
        if xs[i]<minx:
            mini = i 
            minx = xs[i]
    return mini`

If you are using `numpy`, then you can simply use their `numpy.argmin(xs)`.